# Categorical independent in logistic regression R - how do I understand overall effect?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I have a logistic regression with multiple independent variables, one of which is categorical. This variable is education level, and it has six different levels from least educated to most educated.

I know that R defaults to using a reference level (in this case the lowest education level), and then I get coefficients / p-values etc for the 5 other levels individually, as well as all the coefficients for all my other independent variables. I also get separate results for each level (except 1) when calculating marginal effects.

Is there a way I can get R to **not** present 5 separate results for education level, and instead give me one result for the statistical significance and marginal effect of education level? I've been looking for previous posts that may answer this, and can't find a solution.

An example of my code and output is presented below.

```
summary(logit.example2 <- glm(obese13 ~ gender + factor(wgt9) + smoke + 
bfeed + pcgwgt1 + factor(pcgeducation), data = gui2, weights = wgt, 
family = binomial(link = "logit"), na.action=na.omit))
```

Output from R:

```
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.9342  -0.1968  -0.0984  -0.0656   6.2956  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -5.79632    0.35844 -16.171  < 2e-16 ***
gender                 0.25759    0.13594   1.895  0.05811 .  
factor(wgt9)2          2.27494    0.18490  12.303  < 2e-16 ***
factor(wgt9)3          4.46575    0.19359  23.068  < 2e-16 ***
smoke                  0.47266    0.14618   3.233  0.00122 ** 
bfeed                  0.01011    0.14851   0.068  0.94573    
pcgwgt1                0.66464    0.08803   7.551 4.34e-14 ***
factor(pcgeducation)2  0.19437    0.25597   0.759  0.44765    
factor(pcgeducation)3 -0.75131    0.26892  -2.794  0.00521 ** 
factor(pcgeducation)4 -0.60424    0.30015  -2.013  0.04410 *  
factor(pcgeducation)5 -0.59703    0.35817  -1.667  0.09553 .  
factor(pcgeducation)6 -0.57877    0.49763  -1.163  0.24481    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2701.2  on 6238  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1644.3  on 6227  degrees of freedom
  (1056 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 1664.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

Comment: To be clear, it sounds like you want to use `pcgeducation` as a continuous variable instead of a categorical variable. Is that right? Otherwise, I don't know how one would think of an "overall effect" of a categorical variable.

Comment: Looking at the coefficients of educations, it looks like the effect is not linear: first there is an increase in the odds of obesity and then a (linear) reduction. That's my argument for not using education as continuous variable.

Comment: There is a long and complicated answer to your question, but all of it would be about statistics, not programming. For that reason I think this question should go to CV, and I have voted to move it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I know it's not something that can be treated as a continuous variable and I'm not looking for a complicated stats answer - I was just wondering if there is a way I can get the overall effect, rather than separate results, as my full model has a large number of other variables. If there's not, that's fine - thanks for the answers.